# How to remove unused legend limits within scale_color_manual from ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I need to make multiple graphs with similar data that have all the groups remain the same color between graphs. 
I was able to define colors for my groups using `scale_fill_manual` and setting my `values` and `limits`. 
Using `breaks` was not retaining the same color between graphs, but levels solved that issue.

However now I would like to remove the unused groups from the legend since not all of the graphs contain all groups and it seems that `limits` overrides any `breaks` or `drop=TRUE` option I add in.

Is there a way to remove these unused values while also using limits to retain the color between groups without having to explicitly remove it manually?

Attached is an image of one of the graphs I am trying to create, but with the unused limits still in the legend.

[Graph with excess limits in legend][1]

Below is code similar to what I'm trying.
Using this I would like to have *"unknown Chroococcales"* dropped from the legend of graph of **y** automatically and *"unknown Oscillatoriophycideae"* dropped from both **x** & **y**.

I would like it to drop the un-used limits no matter what the limit is (i.e. not have to specify/know the unused ones prior).

````
x <- data.frame ("Genus" =c("unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix" ,"Other", "Microcystis"
,"unknown Synechococcaceae" ,"unknown Chroococcales","unknown Oscillatoriophycideae","Pseudanabaena","Synechococcus", "unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix" ,"Other", "Microcystis"
,"unknown Synechococcaceae"), "RelativeAB"= c( 22, 35, 46, 71, 44, 27, 17, 87, 67, 44, 17, 88, 15, 77, 99, 20), factor= c( "control", "control", "control", "control", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex" ,"magna", "magna", "magna", "magna", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution"))

y <- data.frame ("Genus" =c("unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix" ,"Other", "Microcystis"
,"unknown Synechococcaceae" ,"unknown Oscillatoriophycideae","Pseudanabaena","Synechococcus", "unknown Cyanobacteria","Dolichospermum" ,"Planktothrix" ,"Other", "Microcystis","unknown Synechococcaceae"), "RelativeAB"= c( 22, 35, 46, 71, 44, 27, 17, 87, 67, 44, 17, 15, 77, 99, 20), factor= c( "control", "control", "control", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex", "pulex" ,"magna", "magna", "magna", "magna", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution", "dilution"))

colorscyano <-c("#CC0000", "#FF6000", "#CC9900", "#336600", "#3333FF", "#9933CC", "#FF66CC", "#66FFFF", "#99FF33", "#FFFF00")
breakscyano <- c("unknown Cyanobacteria"
                 ,"Dolichospermum"
                 ,"Planktothrix"
                 ,"Pseudanabaena"
                 ,"Synechococcus"
                 ,"Other"
                 ,"Microcystis"
                 ,"unknown Synechococcaceae"
                 ,"unknown Chroococcales"
                 ,"unknown Oscillatoriophycideae")

labscyano <-c(expression("Unknown" ~"cyanobacteria")
              ,expression(paste(italic("Dolichospermum")))
              ,expression(paste(italic("Planktothrix")))
              ,expression(paste(italic("Pseudanabaena")))
              ,expression(paste(italic("Synechococcus")))
              ,"Other"
              , expression(paste(italic("Microcystis")))
              , expression (paste("unknown", ~italic("Synechococcaceae")))
              , expression (paste("unknown",~italic("Chroococcales")))
              , expression (paste("unknown",~italic("Oscillatoriophycideae"))))

ggplot(x, aes(x=factor, y=RelativeAB, fill=Genus)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black")+
scale_fill_manual(values = colorscyano, limits= breakscyano, labels=labscyano)+
  theme_classic()

ggplot(y, aes(x=factor, y=RelativeAB, fill=Genus)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black")+
scale_fill_manual(values = colorscyano, limits= breakscyano, labels=labscyano)+
  theme_classic()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/akiVF.png
````

Comment: Where do you use the *y* data frame? What is wrong with trial -does it produce legends with unused groups? Maybe including a graph output screenshot will help illustrate and describe what is wrong with these current results and the ideal desired result.

Comment: for me (when I explicitly remove a certain Genus), sucessfully the Colour in question isn't shown in the legend.
`ggplot(x[x$Genus!="unknown Oscillatoriophycideae",], aes(x=factor, y=RelativeAB, fill=Genus)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", size=0.5, color="black")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorscyano, breaks= breakscyano, labels=labscyano)+
  theme_classic()
`
 But I noticed, that you often have a trailing space in the Genus-Variable. Perhaps this causes some problems in the original data (this might be quiet error-prone)

Comment: Alright I fixed my code so there are no excess spaces (I was having issues there too, so thank you :) )

I also attached an example image and elaborated a bit on exaclty what I'm trying to do. 
Hope this helps y'all help me!